# How to limit Crontab text output.

Tags: cron, syslog

When cron runs it outputs text from the script that ran and 
the system calls. Is there a way to limit output?

From This:

```
From x.site  Tue Jul 31 13:32:45 2018
Return-Path: <a.site>
X-Original-To: a
Delivered-To: a.site
Received: by x.site (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 1458910057D; Tue, 31 Jul 2018 13:32:45 -0400 (EDT)
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <a.site>
To: a.site
Subject: Cron <>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=3737>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000>
X-Cron-Env: <DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus>
X-Cron-Env: <LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ab10>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=a>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=a>
Message-Id: <20180731173245.1458910057D@BMCap3.site>
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2018 13:30:04 -0400 (EDT)


Text from script..
```

To Something like this:

```
From x.site  Tue Jul 31 13:32:45 2018
Return-Path: <a.site>
Subject: Cron <>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2018 13:30:04 -0400 (EDT)


Text from script..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bash script...

```
#!/bin/bash
awk ' BEGIN {flag=1}

{
if ($0 ~ /Date:/) { flag=0;
}
if ($0 ~ /From/) {  flag=1;
}
if (flag==0) {print}
}

'
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the output to dev null as part of the command

So the cron command you'd run would be blah > /dev/null

To filter for some, you can use the pipe "blah | either awk or grep"

Comment: I dont want all of the text to go to dev/null

Comment: Then use pipes to send the output to another command like grep, or an awk script to pull only the things that you're interested in